# Unity3d 5.5 Enable Vr for Cardboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm almost new to Unity3D, I've watched this presentation of Unity evengelist made in February 2016:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pK0ZD53gOoE

Evengelist said and showed that to bring project to VR you need to select one checkbox (Virtual Reality Supported). Now in 5.5 version just downloaded, when I select Virtual Reality Supported it says also "you must add at least one VR SDK", also after that checkbox selected when I click play scene, I do not see two eyes screen, just ordinary view. When last year I tried to make VR for Cardboard and loaded Cardboard SDK, scene view showed two screens to each eye in play mode.

So the question - how now make VR that works on Cardboard in Unity3d? Do I still need Cardboard SDK (I don't need magnet input support or similar, just stereo and head movement support)?

Added: I don't have Cardboard SDK option in Unity somehow:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [Unity Blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/09/22/daydream-technical-preview-available-now/), Cardboard support is exclusive to Android only. iOS Cardboard support will be added soon.

> Do I still need Cardboard SDK

I don't think you need the SDK. This is now Native support for Cardboard. Although,you can still download the Cardboard SDK and Unity will automatically use it.

And here is how to enable Cardboard SDK in Unity 5.5.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So you picture of adding cardboard SDK is optional and needed only if Cardboard SDK is added manually to Unity (I don't have it in list of SDKs)? I can safely select None as SDK?

Comment: No, you do that if you want to use Cardboard with Native Unity API. No Cardboard SDK  required when you do this. This is still new and I haven't tried it but I think that's the reason Unity added the Cardboard support in the Editor. They want to enable you to make VR app in the future without external SDK.

Comment: But then as I wrote in just installed Unity I don't have Cardboard SDK entry after enabling VR for Android. Strange or? (I can post a picture of options if needed for understanding in question).

Comment: You mean you don't have `Cardboard` as the drop-down list like in the image in my answer?

Comment: Are you sure that Android is selected like I did in the image I uploaded? Can you upload a picture to prove this?

Comment: I added picture to my question above. When installing Unity I remember I added Android support, if it counts.

Comment: This is very interesting. I will get back to you in a moment. Trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov Hi, I found out that I am using Unity 5.6beta not 5.5. To get that on 5.5, you need to install "Technical Preview" which is a special Unity version for Google VR. You can get that from [here](https://unity3d.com/partners/google/daydream). If you download 5.6, you wont need to download the "Technical Preview" version of Unity. Remember that you can simply download the Google Cardboard SDK if you don't want to install "Technical Preview" or 5.6b.

Comment: Thank you. I've downloading 5.6 now.

Comment: Nice. It should work without SDK. Please read these before working on your VR game. It will let you know the mistakes you should never make. Read [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality). For support, see [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/forums/virtual-reality.80/). Don't forget to accept answer if it solved your problems. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Programmer for your answer, it helped me find what my issue was. However, I've spent literally all of my time over the past few days trying to get Google Cardboard and Unity setup, so I figured I can at least post my answer too.

One problem I initially ran into was that I was trying to use GVR Unity SDK v1.1. There are several bugs in this version, so I reverted back to the GVR Unity SDK v1.0.3. This can be downloaded from the github repo: https://codeload.github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/zip/f391c2436426857899af1c37f0720b3985631eb3

Then, I ran into multiple problems just getting things to run on android, so I found that I have to use build tools version 24.0.1. This can be downloaded using the Android SDK Manager executable.

Lastly, the "cardboard" option wasn't appearing for me as part of the drop downs, just like in the picture posted by the asker. The problem was that I was using a regular version of Unity, when I needed to actually be using the technical preview. This can be downloaded from https://unity3d.com/partners/google/daydream, and I'm running Unity v5.4.2f2-GVR13.

Then the drop down "cardboard" appeared, and I was able to follow google's official instructions (https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started) and get things set up.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up installing the Unity 5.6 Beta and got my Cardboard app built quite simply using the EasyMovieTexture store asset, turning on VR in Player Settings and adding Google Cardboard. It is working great in IOS and Android. I am working on turning off the Google Overlay as my app toggles between Cardboard and a simple 360 view and that is a proving a challenge. It seems from what I have read Google does not want you to turn off their overlay. I might try to do this natively on IOS.